# Linq return null on 'false' where clausule

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a query similar to this:

```
var solution = (from hit2 in Hits.Where(x => x.Combination.Count == 2)
                where IsPossibleHit(hit2, 2, currentSymbols)
                from hit3 in Hits.Where(x => x.Combination.Count == 3)
                where IsPossibleHit(hit3, 3, currentSymbols)
                from hit4 in Hits.Where(x => x.Combination.Count == 4)
                where IsPossibleHit(hit4, 4, currentSymbols)
                from hit5 in Hits.Where(x => x.Combination.Count == 5)
                where IsPossibleHit(hit5, 5, currentSymbols)
                select new
                {
                    hitsList = new List<Hit>(){
                     hit2,
                     hit3,
                     hit4,
                     hit5}
                }).ToList();
```

my problem is that when making the groups, if hit2, and hit3 are possible hits, I need the new object to be created, but, because, hit4 is returning false, the whole combination is discarded.

How can achieve this?

EDIT: I think I didn't make clear what I need, or what my problem is:

My problem is that, when IsPossibleHit(hitN) returns false, the whole combination is discarded (by linq), but what I need is that the object is created anyway, with the hits that returned false set to null, or even not added to the Hit list of the new object.

Comment: If you don't want hit4, then why put it in where clause?

Comment: I need it only if the IsPossibleHit for hit4 returns true. (the query is discarding the combination, not me)

Comment: Then, it's doing what you want,  hit4 is returning false, the whole combination is discarded.  I may misunderstand here.

Comment: You want to return a single list contaning all hits verifying any of `hit.Combination.Count == n && IsPossibleHit(hit, n, currentSymbols)`
 where `n in [2,3,4,5]`?

Comment: @manji: thats exaclty what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
var res = Hits.Where(h => h.Combination.Count >= 2
                       && h.Combination.Count <= 5
                       && IsPossibleHit(h, h.Combination.Count, currentSymbols)
               ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var solution = (from hit2 in Hits.Where(x => x.Combination.Count == 2)
                where IsPossibleHit(hit2, 2, currentSymbols)
                let h3 = from hit3 in Hits.Where(x => x.Combination.Count == 3)
                            where IsPossibleHit(hit3, 3, currentSymbols)
                let h4 = from hit4 in Hits.Where(x => x.Combination.Count == 4)
                            where IsPossibleHit(hit4, 4, currentSymbols)
                let h5 = from hit5 in Hits.Where(x => x.Combination.Count == 5)
                            where IsPossibleHit(hit5, 5, currentSymbols)
                select new
                {
                    hitsList = new List<Hit>(){
                     hit2,
                     h3,
                     h4,
                     h5}
                }).ToList();
```

Try something like that. Please check the syntax, as I haven't run or compiled it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to group by the number of hits and keep only the possible hits in each group? Filter with `Where` and then `GroupBy`:

```
var groupedHits = from h in Hits
                  where h.Combination.Count >= 2 && h.Combination.Count <= 5
                  where IsPossibleHit(h, h.Combination.Count, currentSymbols)
                  group h by h.Combination.Count
```